# Why is this conditional statement failing Terraform plan?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

Im trying to run a loop in terraform that assigns effects from a list based off of a conditional statement. This conditional statement is supposed to ensure that the wanted effect is assigned to the right policy. **The list is saved in a variable and looks like this:**

```
variable "builtin_policies" {
  description = "List of objects consisting of: built in policy names and chosen effect"
  type        = list(object({ displayName = string, effect = string }))
  default = [
    {
      displayName : "API Management service should use a SKU that supports virtual networks",
      effect : "Audit"
    },
    {
      displayName : "Configure API Management services to disable public network access",
      effect : "Disabled"
    },
    {
      displayName : "API Management services should disable public network access",
      effect : "AuditIfNotExists"
    }
]
```

The policy assignment is looping through JSON files filled with policy data. (Duplicates of built-in policies)
**Policy assigment:**

```
resource "azurerm_management_group_policy_assignment" "this" {
  for_each = { for f in local.raw_data : f.name => f }
  name     = "${var.environment}-${random_integer.this.result}"
 
  display_name         = each.value.displayName
  description          = each.value.description
  policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_definition.this[each.key].id
  management_group_id  = data.azurerm_management_group.this.id
  parameters           = jsonencode({
         effect = {
        value = "${values( { for key, value in var.builtin_policies:
         key => value.effect 
         if value.displayName == each.value.displayName} )[0]}"
         }
        })
 
}
```

**The if statement returns the following error:**

```
  Error: Invalid index
on main.tf line 135, in resource "azurerm_management_group_policy_assignment" "this":
135: if value.displayName each.value.displayName} ).0}"
each.value.displayName is "App Service apps should be injected into a virtual network"
var.builtin_policies is list of object with 112 elements
The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no elements.
```

But if i print the following into **terraform console** i get the expected value:

```
> values({for key, value in var.builtin_policies : key => value.effect if value.displayName == "Configure Azure Defender for Azure SQL database to be enabled"})[0]
"Disabled"
>
```

Why is the conditional statement failing? The only difference between the two conditionals is the hard-coded string. But this should not be the problem seeing as the error tells us that the string from each.value.displayName is correct. Any thoughts on what could be the issue here?

Comment: Please don't post error messages and outputs as screenshots.

Comment: I would try to substitute the `"${..}` with the try() method
`try(values( { for key, value in var.builtin_policies:
         key => value.effect 
         if value.displayName == each.value.displayName} )[0], "None")`

Comment: Or maybe, 
`value = try(var.builtin_policies[index([for s in var.builtin_policies : s.displayName], each.value.displayName)].effect. "None")`

Comment: @MarkoE what should I replace it with? Normal copy pasting made the output harder to read..

Comment: @MarcoMassetti Both examples seem to give the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Caspett that's almost impossible, most of the questions are text, but ok. Also, please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: The snippet of code included in your error message doesn't seem to match the corresponding line of code in the code example you shared. Can you make sure you're sharing the latest version of the code that you generated the error message with, and update the question so that they both match?

Comment: @Caspett awesome! I’m posting it as the answer below in case it helps others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to substitute the `"${..}` with the `try()` method

```
try(values( { for key, value in var.builtin_policies:          key => value.effect           if value.displayName == each.value.displayName} )[0], "None")
```

Or maybe,

```
value = try(var.builtin_policies[index([for s in var.builtin_policies : s.displayName], each.value.displayName)].effect, "None")
```